# Static Qtime Default Value

Tags: qt, static, qtime

I have method. This method have static QTime but I want to reset this value if something is happened.

```
static QTime time(QTime::currentTime());

// calculate two new data points:
double key = time.elapsed()/1000;

static double lastPointKey = 0;

if(newPlot == true){
     // like tihs key = 0 ;         
    // lastPointKey = 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`QTime::restart()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#restart) method to reset your timer.

Also, take a look at [`QElapsedTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#details) class. It has a similar API ([`elapsed()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#elapsed), [`restart()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#restart), etc.), however you may find it more suitable for your situation. From the docs:

> `QElapsedTimer` will use the platform's monotonic reference clock in all
>   platforms that support it. This has
>   the added benefit that `QElapsedTimer` is immune to time adjustments,
>   such as the user correcting the time. Also unlike `QTime`, `QElapsedTimer`
>   is immune to changes in the timezone settings, such as daylight-saving
>   periods.